# SuperHero API - Access Token

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to retrieve a json response from SuperHero API but can't find where to create an access token anywhere.
When trying to test a request on the website it says I need to log in via Facebook but there's no option to do that.
Is the Api still active?
Anyone has an access token I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right [on the front page](https://superheroapi.com/) you have the Facebook button to login

[image]

if you don't see it, **check if you have any plugin in your browser that might be blocking it**, and also, might be a good idea to see if you see the button in a **private window**

after accepting the FB web application, you will get the token

[image]

and will be a valid token even if you logout

[image]

---

here's the output when getting info for [MichaelAngelo character](https://superheroapi.com/ids.html):

```
https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/101617...9/450
```

```json
{
   "response":"success",
   "id":"450",
   "name":"Michelangelo",
   "powerstats":{
      "intelligence":"63",
      "strength":"14",
      "speed":"50",
      "durability":"65",
      "power":"59",
      "combat":"75"
   },
   "biography":{
      "full-name":"",
      "alter-egos":"No alter egos found.",
      "aliases":[
         "Mike",
         "Mikey",
         "Mikester",
         "Michaelangelo"
      ],
      "place-of-birth":"-",
      "first-appearance":"-",
      "publisher":"IDW Publishing",
      "alignment":"good"
   },
   "appearance":{
      "gender":"Male",
      "race":"Mutant",
      "height":[
         "-",
         "0 cm"
      ],
      "weight":[
         "- lb",
         "0 kg"
      ],
      "eye-color":"Blue",
      "hair-color":"-"
   },
   "work":{
      "occupation":"-",
      "base":"-"
   },
   "connections":{
      "group-affiliation":"-",
      "relatives":"Leonardo (brother), Donatello (brother), Raphael (brother)"
   },
   "image":{
      "url":"https://www.superherodb.com/pictures2/portraits/10/100/10329.jpg"
   }
}
```

Comment: I see that but it doesn't work. message says:
Facebook login is not currently available in this app.  I don't know if I'm missing something or if it's an error on the page

Comment: maybe blocked by geolocation? try through a VPN, I'm in Denmark, and I can see the login correctly...

Comment: @Hades could you solve the problem?